# How to add a negated list of names to match in a .network configuration file in /etc/systemd/network/

Tags: networking, network-interface, systemd-networkd

How can I add a negated list of names to match? I want to match all interfaces that do not start with veth or vir. Is the below correct?

```
[Match]
Name=!veth* !vir*

[DHCPv4]
UseDNS=no
```

Thanks!

Comment: can't test myself right now, it should be `=!` to negate the entire list, not repeat `!` for each glob.

Comment: @frostschutz Shouldn't there be some documentation about it somewhere? Thanks

Comment: `man systemd.network` on Name=